# How do you get access to the DOM of the currently active tab from a background script in a chrome extension?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, contextmenu

I have a chrome extension that adds a couple of items to the context menu when a passage of text is highlighted.  When the menu item is clicked, a query is sent to a server, and the response is shown to the user.  My extension works, but there are two issues I would like to see done better.

The first is that the query might take several seconds, and I would like to show the user some indication that the query has been sent and is waiting.  Changing the cursor to a wait would work, but something like a floating HTML block or a tooltip would be better.  But when I try to do this in my javascript, the document modifications end up on the background page, not on the page the user is currently looking at.  How do I get access to the DOM of current page?

Second, and related, my extension currently displays the results of the query by opening a popup window.  I have to try to send a message from the background page to the popup window, but the timing is sometimes funny and the message gets sent before the popup is ready to receive it, so it misses it.  Really I'd just like the "popup" to be an added html element in the currently active page, that I can interact with using javascript.  I think I can do this if I can get access to the DOM on that page, but I don't know how.  Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Look at using [content scripts](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html).

Comment: So in order to do this I have to have a content script that matches every page (or at least every page I hope to be able to do this in)?  I was hoping to avoid having to request those permissions...  Seems like there should be a way to just show a simple box over the html, but I guess I can see that if you give access to the DOM to a script, it can do whatever it wants with it, so for security you have to say that the script could send all of your data on every page to some server...  That's too bad if there's no other way.

Comment: You can use [programmatic injection](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html#pi) instead of matching every site, that way you inject it on demand, but you still need permissions for that host.

Comment: Thanks, programmatic injection looks like what I want.  But, sadly, I will have to ask for blanket permission for every site.  Oh well.  From a security standpoint, I can understand the reasoning for having the permissions work that way.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/activeTab.html